# Image Not Displaying From The Path That is Manually Saved to Another Model in Django

Tags: python, django, image, sorl-thumbnail

I have two models with `ImageField`. *I am using `sorl-thumbnail` to generate thumbnail*. The first model has a form binded to it while the second gets its `ImageField` populated from the first one, when it is saved.

**models.py**:

```
#the first model
class NewImage(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField()
#second
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = NewImage
    fields = {'thumbnail'}
```

**views.py**:

```
def saveImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      user = Users.objects.get(id = 1)
      imageForm = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if imageForm.is_valid():
            upload_image = imageForm.save(commit=False)
            upload_image.time_created = timezone.now()
            upload_image.save()
            #save image path to user who uploaded it.
            user.thumbnail = upload_image.thumbnail
            user.save()
```

If I pass these to my templates:
`image = NewImage.objects.get(id = 1)` and `user = Users.objects.get(id = 1)`.

This displays my image:

```
{% thumbnail image.thumbnail "200x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="..{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

But this only display a square box:

```
{% thumbnail user.thumbnail "200x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="..{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Both images have a link to images `sorl-thumbnail` created in *cache* folder.

Why is this happening and how can I get my `user.thumbnail` displayed?

Comment: Why didn't you use a foreignkey field instead?

Comment: Anyway to debug this issue, i suggest you to go to your database table(ie, user table) and check wheather the data (ie, the path,which is usually relative) is saved in the database or not?

Comment: @Ajeeb.K.P: I have done that and it is saved there. I mean the path to the uploaded image.

Comment: Are they same, ie thumbnail in Users and NewImage?

Comment: Yes, they are as I explained in my question. They are the same.

Comment: Did you inspect the element in the browser are the linked to same. And can you try change second `thumbnail user.thumbnail "200x100" crop="center" as im` to `athumbnail user.thumbnail "200x100" crop="center" as im2` and rest according to this change. Try reloading the page with browser console opened.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
user.thumbnail = upload_image.thumbnail.name
user.save()
```

one more thing:

instead of doing `upload_image.time_created = timezone.now()`
you can change your model to include `auto_now_add=True` which will automatically save the time_created to time it was actually created.
like this:

```
class NewImage(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure. Or is it `user.thumbnail = upload_image.thumbnail.url
user.save()`

Comment: I think url is to be saved.

Comment: Look at the question, the url is used to display the file. Right?

Comment: But, a better solution is to use ForeignKeyField here. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: .url only includes media_url in front of image path, even when you save user.thumbnail to upload_image.thumbnail, and do .url later on, it will work

Comment: By the way, what you think about ForeigKeyField here? I believe in DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: an unecessary hit to database every time image is accessed where as just saving it sorts the issue for once and all

Comment: oops something like this has worked for me on few occasions.. anywayz.. please post the solution once you are done with it.